# Trouble serializing with to JSON in Java using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Good morning guys!

I have a JSON strings that looks like:

```
{
   "StatusCode":0,
   "Message":null,
   "ExecutionTime":0,
   "ResponseData":[
        {"Name":"name1","SiteId":"1234","Type":"Type1","X":"1234567","Y":"123456"},
        {"Name":"Name2","SiteId":"2134","Type":"Type2","X":"1234567","Y":"1234567"},
        {"Name":"Name3","SiteId":"3241","Type":"Type3","X":"1234567","Y":"1234567"},
        {"Name":"Name4","SiteId":"4123","Type":"Type4","X":"123456","Y":"123456"}
    ]
}
```

I want to create an object where I can retrieve the `X`and `Y` values.

I've been trying to use Jackson to serialize the JSON string, without success. I've created two extra classes for Jackson to use. One class for the top layer, `StatusCode`, `Message`, `ExecutionTime` and `ResponseData` which looks like

```
public class PL {
private Long statusCode;
private String executionTime;
private String message;
private ResponseData responseData;
public PL(){
}

public void setStatusCode(Long statusCode){
  this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public Long getStatusCode(){
  return this.statusCode;
}

public void setExecutionTime(String executionTime){
  this.executionTime = executionTime;
}
public String getExecutionTime(){
  return this.executionTime;
}

public void setMessage(String message){
  this.message = message;
}
public String getMessage(){
  return this.message;
}

public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData){
  this.responseData = responseData;
}
public ResponseData getResponseData(){
  return this.responseData;
}
}
```

Where `ReponseData` is returned as an object, and then I have another class for serializing `ResponseData` which looks like

```
public class ResponseData {

private String name;
private String siteId;
private String type;
private String x;
private String y;

public ResponseData(){
}

public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
  return this.name;
}

public void setSiteId(String siteId){
  this.siteId = siteId;
}
public String getSiteId(){
  return this.siteId;
}

public void setType(String type){
  this.type = type;
}
public String setType(){
  return this.type;
}

public void setX(String x){
  this.x = x;
}
public String getX(){
  return this.x;
}

public void setY(String y){
  this.y = y;
}
public String getY(){
  return this.y;
}
}
```

I then create an `ObjectMapper` with

```
private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

and try to so read the values with

```
ResponseData e = mapper.readValue(result.toString(), ResponseData.class);
```

and end up with the exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "StatusCode" (class MyClass.ResponseData), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "x", "y", "siteId", "name", "type"])

as if it can't parse the first entry, `StatusMessage`. Even if I remove the second class and only try to parse the first four entries where i return `ResponseData` as a `String` I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, in `PL` you should have a `List<ResponseData>` not a simple `ResponseData` attribute. As you can see, in the JSON, `ResponseData` is an array `"ResponseData":[...]` so it will be deserialized as a `List`. Each element of the list will be a `ResponseData` object as you defined it.

Then you have a case issue, you have upper cases in the JSON that you don't have in your class attributes. You can use the `@JsonProperty` ([See API](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)) annotation to overcome the problem, this way:

```
class PL {
    @JsonProperty("StatusCode")
    private Long statusCode;
    @JsonProperty("ExecutionTime")
    private String executionTime;
    @JsonProperty("Message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("ResponseData")
    private List<ResponseData> responseDatas;

    public PL(){
    }

    // getters/Setters  

}


class ResponseData {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("SiteId")
    private String siteId;
    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("X")
    private String x;
    @JsonProperty("Y")
    private String y;

    public ResponseData(){
    }

    // getters/Setters  

}
```

Then read your JSON as a `PL` object, like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PL pl = mapper.readValue(json, PL.class);
for(ResponseData rd : pl.getResponseDatas()) {
    System.out.println(rd.getX());
    System.out.println(rd.getY());
}
```

This outputs:

```
1234567
123456
1234567
1234567
1234567
1234567
123456
123456
```

Comment: One more thing: Is there any easy way just access the first X and Y values? I don't really understand that loop..

Comment: if you only want the first one, you can do  `pl.getResponseDatas().get(0).getX()` and `pl.getResponseDatas().get(0).getY()`

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly straightforward. Define your response structure using composition of classes. It is unfortunate to use capitalised fields in JSON, which out-of-the-box requires capitalised field names in the Java DTO. Still those can be easily mapped to conventional low-case names either by using the *ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES* modifier on the `ObjectMapper` or by annotating fields with corresponding names. I prefer a property on the `ObjectMapper` as it keeps the DTO independent of the serialisation code and this technique is used in the test below (the test is green):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestDeserialization50386188 {

    public static class Response {

        public static class ResponseDataType {
            public String name;
            public String siteId;
            public String type;
            public long x;
            public long y;
        }

        public int statusCode;
        public String message;
        public long executionTime;
        public List<ResponseDataType> ResponseData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static final String data = "{\"StatusCode\":0,\"Message\":null,\"ExecutionTime\":0,\"ResponseData\":[{\"Name\":\"name1\",\"SiteId\":\"1234\",\"Type\":\"Type1\",\"X\":\"1234567\",\"Y\":\"123456\"},{\"Name\":\"Name2\",\"SiteId\":\"2134\",\"Type\":\"Type2\",\"X\":\"1234567\",\"Y\":\"1234567\"},{\"Name\":\"Name3\",\"SiteId\":\"3241\",\"Type\":\"Type3\",\"X\":\"1234567\",\"Y\":\"1234567\"},{\"Name\":\"Name4\",\"SiteId\":\"4123\",\"Type\":\"Type4\",\"X\":\"123456\",\"Y\":\"123456\"}]}";

    @Test
    public void deserialize_response_withJackson_ok() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
          .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

        Response response = mapper.readValue(data, Response.class);

        assertEquals(4, response.ResponseData.size());
        assertEquals(1234567, response.ResponseData.get(2).x);
        assertEquals(1234567, response.ResponseData.get(2).y);
    }
}
```

You fill find the project with the executable test on [this dedicated GitHub repo](https://github.com/osklyar/stack-overflow/blob/master/src/test/java/TestDeserialization50386188.java).

The ["Clean Code" book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Uncle Bob does not really recommend the overuse of getters and setters so common in Java for DTOs, which a `Response` class is. Still you can replace all public fields with getter/setter pairs if you like but the clarity will suffer with no obvious gain on quality.

Answer (score 1):

Use List to receive arrays.

```
private Long statusCode;
private String executionTime;
private String message;
public List<ResponseDataType> ResponseData
```

and it will do everything automatically.